# which pointer statement should i correct to avoid segmentation fault

Tags: c

here is my code, when i execute it, it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". what kind of mistakes did I do?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
  void swap(int *p1,int *p2);
  int a,b, *ptr1,*ptr2;

  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  *ptr1=a;
  *ptr2=b;
  swap(ptr1,ptr2);
}

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
 int t;
 t=*a;
 *a=*b;
 *b=t;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `*ptr1=a;` try `ptr1=&a;`, and the same for `ptr2`.

Comment: Are you trying to swap the values of `main`'s variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: Actually, I d like to figure out in the pointer swap method, are the pointers swapped or just the value stored in the pointer swapped

Answer (score 3):

`*ptr1 = a;` and `*ptr2 = b;` are your errors, and really you should check that the return value of `scanf` is 2 to indicate that both variables were set to something.

Neither `ptr1` nor `ptr2` point to anything when the deferences are attempted, so the behaviour on dereferencing them is undefined. A core dump is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Did you want `ptr1 = &a;` and `ptr2 = &b;`? Or call more simply with

```
swap(&a, &b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you did here is doing:

```
*ptr1=a;
*ptr2=b;
```

you're trying to dereference unitialized pointers, pointing to indeterminate memory location, which are invalid. This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to ensure that the pointers are pointing to valid memory location before you can dereference them.

In your case, it looks like you want the pointers to point to the variables, so changing the code to be

```
ptr1 = &a;
ptr2 = &b;
```

should do.